# See the Breakpoint column in designer

Tags: visual-studio

I cannot see the column in the designer where the breakpoints go. I can still set them, just don't see them. I can only add them by right click on the line, instead of clicking the line in the column to the left and set them. I am thinking it is a setting?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Designer?  I can only guess you meant the text editor, red dot on the far left indicates a breakpoint.  Tools > Options > Text Editor > General, ensure the "Indicator margin" checkbox is ticked.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks